# C# catch cefsharp errors

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I use Cefsharp to play video, but it doesn't support MP4, and I use VLC plugin to play MP4 files. It plays MP4 files very well. But after one or two days, There is an error: 
[image: Error]

[image]

I just want to catch this error and restart the computer. This is my code:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("debug-plugin-loading", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-outdated-plugins", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("always-authorize-plugins", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-npapi", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("enable-system-flash");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-system-flash", "1");


Cef.Initialize(settings);
Cef.AddWebPluginPath(this.m_appPath + "VLC\\npvlc.dll");
Cef.AddWebPluginDirectory(this.m_appPath + "VLC");
mainWebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
```

Sorry about my English. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Implement your own subprocess or download and modify the source to add a try catch. Each version has it's own branch

Comment: I'm going to try this. thanks a lot.